# Overload resolution ambiguity. All these functions match when calling a java function that accepts both primitive and object arguments

Tags: java, kotlin

I have some java methods that look like this:

```
String doSomeMath(int num){
 if (num<0) 
  return "value not loaded yet, please wait";
 else
  return String.valueOf(num);
}
String doSomeMath(Integer num){
 if (num==null) 
  return "value not loaded yet, please wait";
 else
  return String.valueOf(num);
}
```

But in kotlin if I try to call these methods

```
val i1:Int=whatever()
val i2:Int?=nullableWhatever()
val str1=doSomeMath(i1)
val str2=doSomeMath(i2)
```

Obviously `i1` is most likely an `int` and `i2` definitely an `Integer` yet kotlin doesn't think so and gives `Overload resolution ambiguity. All these functions match` for both line 3 and line 4.
How can I cast `i1` and `i2` to java `int` or `Integer`?

Comment: which version of Kotlin are you using? It seems that all is fine on 1.3.41

Comment: android studio says Current Kotlin plugin version :1.3.21-release-Studio3.1-1 \n You have the latest version of the plugin installed.

Comment: This is the version of the Kotlin plugin in AS. There is `build.gradle` in the root of your project. More likely the version of Kotlin is declared in the `buildscript` section

Comment: `ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.41'` can anyone else confirm that it's not just my build that ran into this problem?

Comment: @AndreiTanana just noticed that kotlin does have an overload method for primitves and objects, ie it's ok in kotlin to write `fun doSomeMath(num:Int):String{..} fun doSomeMath(num:Int?):String{..}` and these methods won't cause ambiguity.